# Import private macro from Github to Warp10

Tags: warpscript

Do you know how to import a macro from Github to Warp10 using WarpScript ?

```
[ 'https://github.com/miton18/test-ws/blob/master' ] WF.SETREPOS

WF.GETREPOS

'miton18/test-ws' 'me' IMPORT

[ NEWGTS ] @me/renameWithLabel
```

content of `renameWithLabel.mc2` on Git:

```
<% DROP DUP LABELS $label GET RENAME %> LMAP
```

Answer (score 1):

as explained here: https://blog.senx.io/share-your-warpscript-macros/

```
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miton18/test-ws/master'  WF.ADDREPO
WF.GETREPOS // check...
[] @utils/renameWithLabel
```

Your macro must be in a sub folder ;)

But for private repos, try https://user:pass@xxxx or modify the Warp 10 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you always need a subdirectory (as every macros repos, even the `macros` directory of your Warp 10 egress)

[IMPORT](https://www.warp10.io/doc/IMPORT) is usefull if the full path of your macro contains lots of subdirectories.

```
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pi-r-p/warpscript/master' WF.ADDREPO
'viz' 'a' IMPORT  
[] @a/juxtaposeGTS  //now I can call a instead of viz.
```

[playable warpscript here.](https://snapshot.senx.io/000596c4743b29ba-0-2-192caceb1e9f867a)

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/senx/WarpFleetSynchronizer ;)
You will be able to deploy a private WarpFleet resolver with git repos synchronization.